# Removing directives from x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am wondering if there is a way to remove directives from x86 assembly.  For example,  .macro and .rept are things that I would want to expand.

Also, are there any references or could someone say when directives are evaluated; e.g. at load time?  Do any directives, such as .word, have meaning at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're after in the first part of your question.  You could simply assemble the program and then view the output with a disassembler; that would cause everything to be expanded.

As to your second question, all directives are handled by the assembler.  None have any runtime meaning.  In fact, they don't exist at all by that point.

Comment: Ah, for part 1, I wasn't sure if the directives were expanded during assembly or when the file was loaded to be run (I was told they were expanded during load time, which I didn't believe, hence I asked).  Thank you!!